# jQuery animation glitch

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation

I'm currently working on a college project which involves making a dynamic website. I've currently got a section on my website which is a feedback form that when a button is pressed, it slides down using the **slideDown()** function in jQuery.

The issue that I'm currently having is extremely weird and is nothing that I've ever seen before. Basically what needs to happen is when the button "Feedback" is pressed, the article named Feedback should slide down. What is happening is when the button is pressed, instead of a smooth animation it just appears, almost as if it skips the animation. After this I started debugging the website and I noticed that in the background the animation is working but doesn't seem to be appearing? So what could be causing this?

Any help I can get on this I would highly appreciate as I've spent hours trying to figure out the problem with no successful results. If you require any more information ask and I'm not entirely sure I'm allowed to put it here but this site is on my private domain which I can give to people to physically see the issue, thanks

**Here's the jQuery Library I've implemented:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Here's the script that should draw the animation:**

```
$('#nav-6').click(function(){
            $('.feedback').slideDown(2000);
        });
```

**Here's the feedback.php**

```
<article class="feedback">
<h1 class="filler-header">Feedback Form</h1>
<section>
    <form action="#" name="feedback">
        <p>Name: </p><input type="text" class="fb-field"/>
        <p>Email: </p><input type="text" class="fb-field"/>
        <p>Description: </p><input type="text" class="fb-field"/>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="fb-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

**Finally here is the CSS for all things relevant:**

```
.feedback {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
background-color: #1e1e1e;
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
position: relative;
display: none;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? What browsers have you checked?

Comment: Hi, i've made a codepen, and it works for me (on chrome at least) http://codepen.io/jibe84/pen/wBBZPV

Comment: @Jeff Due to fact that it's only a college project, I'm making it for Chrome as I would have to make another stylesheet for other browsers, which is going to take too much time.

Comment: @jibe_84 Ah so this is going to be one of two issues. One being that I've implemented this HTML using php includes. Two being that other sections of the website is conflicting with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome v38 and it works.

```js
$('#nav-6').click(function(){
            $('.feedback').slideDown(2000);
 });
```

```css
.feedback {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
background-color: #eee;
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
position: relative;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="nav-6">click me</button>
<article class="feedback">
<h1 class="filler-header">Feedback Form</h1>
<section>
    <form action="#" name="feedback">
        <p>Name: </p><input type="text" class="fb-field"/>
        <p>Email: </p><input type="text" class="fb-field"/>
        <p>Description: </p><input type="text" class="fb-field"/>
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="fb-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</section>
</article>
```

Comment: Would it be ok to give you my URL to it? Saves me pastes lots of code.

Comment: also let us know what version number of chrome. Are you on Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: Has anyone been able to figure it out?